# Error con TableSorter - JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy queriendo ordenar, pero cuando le doy click a las cabezeras, ocurre esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo hago con una tabla creada en duro(datos en duro) funciona perfectamente, también cuando los datos ya están cargados desde un inicio con PHP, pero cuando lleno la tabla desde los comboBox, ocurre eso.

HTML

```
<table class="datos" id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                th con los cabezales
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tabla">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

PHP para llenar tabla(de esta misma forma lleno la tabla sin necesidad del comboBox y funciona)

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

if (isset($_POST["selected"])){
    $ubigeo = $_POST["selected"];
    $consulta = Query;

    $queryResult = $pdo->query($consulta);

    $html = "";
    $string = '.';
    while ($row = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $html .=
            '<tr class="fila">'.
            '<td>'.
            td con las filas
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo $html;
}else{
}
?>
```

JS para llenar la tabla mediante los comboBox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#provincia").on('change', function () {
        $("#provincia option:selected").each(function () {
            elegido="9";
            $.post("datos/tablaCandidatos.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
                $("#tabla").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Porque no pruebas a llamar la función de sortable cada que cargas los datos así siempre estará nueva la función para todos los controles del DOM

$.post("datos/tablaCandidatos.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
                $("#tabla").html(data);
FUNCION_SORTABLE();
            });

Comment: Funcionó perfecto !!!.
Como no conosco muy bien JQuery, no pensé que podia incluir ".tablesorter()" dentro de donde estaba la función que llenaba mi tabla, gracias estimado